# Creating with nested resources in order in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have a model called `Page`, which has_many Lines, and `Page` accepts nested attributes for `Page`, if I do

```
Page.create({"lines_attributes" : [{"foo1": "bar1"}, {"foo2": "bar2"}]})
```

Is there any way to ensure that the line

```
{"foo1": "bar1"}
```

Will be inserted before

```
{"foo2": "bar2"}
```

Comment: Does it matter if it isn't? It seems like you should have some sort of other data to tell the order of the lines and not rely on the insertion of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are already inserted in the right order, but the database does not guarantee the right order when you select for it. You need to add another attribute into your Page model `position`, so you can sort the data as you prefer. The easiest way to do so is by using `acts_as_list`-gem:

https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list

Example:

```
> rails generate scaffold Page page_number:integer
> rails generate scaffold Line content position:integer page_id:integer
```

**app/models/page.rb**

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lines, -> { order("position ASC") }

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lines
end
```

**app/models/line.rb**

```
class Line < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page
  acts_as_list scope: :page
end
```

And add `acts_as_list` into your Gemfile.

```
2.1.0 :001 > Page.create({lines_attributes:[{content: "bar1"}, {content: "bar2"}]})
2.1.0 :002 > puts Page.last.lines.to_yaml
---
- !ruby/object:Line
attributes:
    id: 5
content: bar1
position: 1
page_id: 6
created_at: 2014-07-11 09:38:56.800269000 Z
updated_at: 2014-07-11 09:38:56.800269000 Z
- !ruby/object:Line
attributes:
    id: 6
content: bar2
position: 2
page_id: 6
created_at: 2014-07-11 09:38:56.807034000 Z
updated_at: 2014-07-11 09:38:56.807034000 Z
=> nil
```